# Read python stdout as string

Tags: java, python, string, python-2.7, stdout

In Java, I can read the stdout as a string using

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(stdout));
String toUse = stdout.toString();

/**
 * do all my fancy stuff with string `toUse` here
 */

//Now that I am done, set it back to the console
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
```

Can someone please show me an equivalent way of doing this in python? I know different flavors of this question has been asked a number of times, such as [Python: Closing a for loop by reading stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811374/python-closing-a-for-loop-by-reading-stdout) and [How to get stdout into a string (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472760/how-to-get-stdout-into-a-string-python). But I have a feeling that I don't need to import subprocess to get what I need, as what I need is simpler than that. I am using pydev on eclipse, and I program is very simple.

I already tried

```
from sys import stdout

def findHello():
  print "hello world"
  myString = stdout

  y = 9 if "ell" in myString else 13
```

But that does not seem to be working. I get some compaints about opening file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood what your trying to do properly, something like this will use a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object to capture anything you write to `stdout`, which will allow you to get the value:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

stringio = StringIO()
previous_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = stringio

# do stuff

sys.stdout = previous_stdout

myString = stringio.getvalue()
```

Of course, this suppresses the output actually going to the original `stdout`. If you want to print the output to the console, but still capture the value, you could use something like this:

```
class TeeOut(object):
    def __init__(self, *writers):
        self.writers = writers

    def write(self, s):
        for writer in self.writers:
            writer.write(s)
```

And use it like this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

stringio = StringIO()
previous_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = TeeOut(stringio, previous_stdout)

# do stuff

sys.stdout = previous_stdout

myString = stringio.getvalue()
```